# Stratified sampling doesn't seem to change randomForest results

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using the randomForest package in R to build several species distribution models. My response variable is binary (0 - absence or 1-presence), and pretty unbalanced - for some species the ratio of absences:presences is 37:1. This imbalance  (or zero-inflation) leads to questionable out-of-bag error estimates - the larger the ratio of absences to presence, the lower my out-of-bag (OOB) error estimate.

To compensate for this imbalance, I wanted to implement stratified sampling such that each tree in the random forest included an equal (or at least less imbalanced) number of results from both the presence and absences category. I was surprised that there doesn't seem to be any difference in the stratified and unstratified model OOB error estimates. See my code below:

#### Without stratification

```
> set.seed(25)
> HHrf<- randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Dist2Shr+ DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region) + Chla , data = bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
> HHrf
Call:
  randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Dist2Shr + DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region) + Chla, data = bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 19.1%
Confusion matrix:
    0  1 class.error
0 422 18  0.04090909
1  84 10  0.89361702
```

#### With stratification

```
> HHrf_strata<- randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Chla + Dist2Shr+ DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region), data = bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE, strata = bll_HH$HH_Pres, sampsize = ceiling(.632*nrow(bll_HH)))
> HHrf

Call:
 randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Dist2Shr + DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region) + Chla, data = bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 19.1%
Confusion matrix:
    0  1 class.error
0 422 18  0.04090909
1  84 10  0.89361702
```

Is there a reason that I am getting the same results in both cases? For the strata argument, I specify my response variable, HH_Pres. For the sampsize argument, I specify that it should just be 63.2% of the entire dataset.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or is this to be expected?

Thanks,

Liza

To reproduce this problem:

Sample data: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-JMocik79JzY3B4U3NoU3kyNW8/edit

Code:

```
bll = read.csv("bll_Nov2013_NMV.csv", header=TRUE)
HH_Pres <- bll$HammerHeadALL_Presence

Slope <-bll$Slope
Dist2Shr <-bll$Dist2Shr
Bathy <-bll$Bathy2
Chla <-bll$GSM_Chl_Daily_MF
SST <-bll$SST_PF_daily
Region <- bll$Region
MoonPhase <-bll$MoonPhase
DaylightHours <- bll$DaylightHours
bll_HH <- data.frame(HH_Pres, Slope, Dist2Shr, Bathy, Chla, SST, DaylightHours, MoonPhase, Region)
set.seed(25)

HHrf<- randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Dist2Shr+ DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region) + Chla , data = bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
HHrf
set.seed(25)
HHrf_strata<- randomForest(formula = factor(HH_Pres) ~ SST + Chla + Dist2Shr+ DaylightHours + Bathy + Slope + MoonPhase + factor(Region), data = bll_HH, strata = bll_HH$HH_Pres, sampsize = c(100, 50), ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, importance = TRUE)
HHrf
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but... you're naming the second model as `HHrf_strata`, but checking the output for `HHrf` both times... shouldn't the last line be `HHrf_strata` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the `sampsize` argument should be a vector that is the same length as the number of classes in your data set. If you specify a factor variable in the `strata` argument, then `sampsize` should be given a vector that is the same length as the number of factors in the `strata` argument. I am not sure it performs as you describe in your question, but it has been a while since I have used the `randomForest` function.

From the help files, it says:

> `strata`
>
> A (factor) variable that is used for stratified sampling.
>
> `sampsize`:
>
> Size(s) of sample to draw. For classification, if sampsize is a vector
>   of the length the number of strata, then sampling is stratified by
>   strata, and the elements of sampsize indicate the numbers to be drawn
>   from the strata.

For example, since your classification has 2 distinct classes, you need to give `sampsize` a vector of length 2 that specifies how many observations you want to sample from each class during training time.

e.g. `sampsize=c(100,50)`

Furthermore, you can specify the names of the groups to be extra clear.

e.g. `sampsize=c('0'=100, '1'=50)`

An example from the help files that uses the `sampsize` argument, to clarify:

```
## stratified sampling: draw 20, 30, and 20 of the species to grow each tree.
data(iris)
(iris.rf2 <- randomForest(iris[1:4], iris$Species, sampsize=c(20, 30, 20)))
```

EDIT: Added some notes about the `strata` argument in `randomForest`.

EDIT: Make sure the `strata` argument is given a factor variable!

e.g. try `strata = factor(HH_Pres), sampsize = c(...)` where `c(...)` is a vector that is the same length as `length(levels(factor(bll_HH$HH_Pres)))`

EDIT:

OK, I tried running the code with your data, and it works for me.

```
# Fix up the data set to have HH_Pres and Region as factors
bll_HH$Region <- factor(bll_HH$Region)
bll_HH$HH_Pres <- factor(bll_HH$HH_Pres)

# Original RF code
set.seed(25)
HHrf <- randomForest(formula=HH_Pres ~ SST + Dist2Shr + DaylightHours + Bathy +
                      Slope + MoonPhase + Chla + Region,
                    data=bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, 
                    importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
HHrf

# Output
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 18.91%
# Confusion matrix:
#     0  1 class.error
# 0 425 15  0.03409091
# 1  86  8  0.91489362

# Take 63.2% from each class
mySampSize <- ceiling(table(bll_HH$HH_Pres) * 0.632)

set.seed(25)
HHrf <- randomForest(formula=HH_Pres ~ SST + Dist2Shr + DaylightHours + Bathy +
                       Slope + MoonPhase + Chla + Region,
                     data=bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, 
                     importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit,
                     sampsize=mySampSize)
HHrf
# Output
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 18.91%
# Confusion matrix:
#     0  1 class.error
# 0 424 16  0.03636364
# 1  85  9  0.90425532
```

Note that the OOB error estimate is the same in this case, even if we only use 63.2% of the data from each of the classes in our bootstrap samples. This is probably due to using sample sizes that are proportional to the class distribution in your training data, and the relatively small size of your data set. Let's try changing `mySampSize` to make sure it REALLY worked.

```
# Change mySampSize. Sample 100 from class 0 and 50 from class 1
mySampSize[1] <- 100
mySampSize[2] <- 50

set.seed(25)
HHrf <- randomForest(formula=HH_Pres ~ SST + Dist2Shr + DaylightHours + Bathy +
                       Slope + MoonPhase + Chla + Region,
                     data=bll_HH, ntree = 500, replace = FALSE, 
                     importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit,
                     sampsize=mySampSize)
HHrf
# Output
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 21.16%
# Confusion matrix:
#     0  1 class.error
# 0 382 58   0.1318182
# 1  55 39   0.5851064
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I understand what the sampsize argument a lot better now. Unfortunately I am still getting the same OOB error estimate from the stratified and non-stratified models. I was wondering, is it weird that when I print the stratified model after running it, the "sampsize" and "strata" arguments no longer appear after the Call:? See my original example.

Comment: @Liza I cannot try your example without some sample data. But, try changing the `strata` and `sampsize` arguments - they may not be valid, and `randomForest` may be ignoring them.

Comment: Here is some sample data. If you have a chance to test it out, I would really appreciate it! [Sample data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-JMocik79JzY3B4U3NoU3kyNW8/edit). I'll edit my original example to include all of the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax seems to be working fine for me on your data. The OOB is 32.21% and the class error(s): 0.32, 0.29. I did kick up the number of Bootstraps to 1000. I always recommend using indexing to define a RF model. In certain circumstances, symbolic syntax seems to be unstable.

```
require(randomForest)
  HHrf <- read.csv("bll_HH.csv")
    set.seed(25)    
( rf.mdl <- randomForest( y=as.factor(HHrf[,"HH_Pres"]), x=HHrf[,2:ncol(HHrf)],
                          strata=as.factor(HHrf[,"HH_Pres"]), sampsize=c(50,50),
                          ntree=1000) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. What I noticed is that my error rate when using `importance = TRUE` changes significantly. It is not the same as if I did not choose stratification with sampling.

For me it ended up being a tradeoff in not having an importance/accuracy score for my classification tree. It appears to be one of many bugs in this implementation.