# how to use classwt in randomForest of R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a highly imbalanced data set with target class instances in the following ratio `60000:1000:1000:50` (i.e. a total of 4 classes). I want to use `randomForest` for making predictions of the target class.

So, to reduce the class imbalance, I played with `sampsize` parameter, setting it to `c(5000, 1000, 1000, 50)` and some other values, but there was not much use of it. Actually, the accuracy of the 1st class decreased while I played with `sampsize`, though the improvement in other class predictions was very minute.

While digging through the archives, I came across two more features of `randomForest()`, which are `strata` and `classwt` that are used to offset class imbalance issue.

All the documents upon `classwt` were old (generally belonging to the 2007, 2008 years), which all suggested not the use the `classwt` feature of `randomForest` package in `R` as it does not completely implement its complete functionality like it does in `fortran`. So the first question is:
**Is `classwt` completely implemented now in `randomForest` package of R? If yes, what does passing `c(1, 10, 10, 10)` to the `classwt` argument represent?** (Assuming the above case of 4 classes in the target variable)

Another argument which is said to offset class imbalance issue is stratified sampling, which is always used in conjunction with `sampsize`. I understand what `sampsize` is from the documentation, but there is not enough documentation or examples which gave a clear insight into using `strata` for overcoming class imbalance issue. So the second question is:
**What type of arguments have to be passed to `strata`in `randomForest` and what does it represent?**

I guess the word ***weight*** which I have not explicitly mentioned in the question should play a major role in the answer.

Comment: I would run a forest on only the three smaller classes. That will give you a sense of how well a rf model could possibly distinguish those three classes without the dominant class at all. If the accuracy is still fairly low, then class imbalance is probably not your real problem, rather those three classes are just not easily distinguished with the features you have.

Comment: Thanks @joran . Sorry for a little confusion, here is the actual class instance ratio which I also have changed in the question: 60000:1000:1000:50. Do you think omitting the first class in this case is going to help? Because when I run RF with all 4 classes I get the accuracy in the following order for each class: c(90%, 70%, 70%, less than 10%). I'm more concerned about improving the accuracy of 4th class which is less than 10%. And one more thing is, is the `classwt` correctly implemented in `randomForest` of R as of now?

Comment: As for `classwt` implementation - I suppose it isn't implemented, because http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/NEWS
you can read that "* Implement the new scheme of handling classwt in classification." is in wishlist.

Comment: Examples of how to use `strata` and `sampsize` can be now found on two SO posts, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842059/stratified-sampling-with-random-forests-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150525/stratified-sampling-doesnt-seem-to-change-randomforest-results)

Comment: Yes, I don't think `classwt` is implemented. I tried it with different values and my results are identical to running with the default setting, where `classwt = NULL`

Comment: classwt IS implemented.  it is changing my predictions.

Comment: `classwt` is correctly passed to the underlying code of `randomForest`, [check it](https://github.com/cran/randomForest/blob/master/R/randomForest.default.R#L212).

Comment: Try larger values. I found that I only got results when I increased the weights a few orders of magnitude. For example, c(1,10,50) was unable to change a thing, but c(1,10,50000) started to make a difference. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

`classwt` is correctly passed on to `randomForest`, check this example:

```
library(randomForest)
rf = randomForest(Species~., data = iris, classwt = c(1E-5,1E-5,1E5))
rf

#Call:
# randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris, classwt = c(1e-05, 1e-05, 1e+05)) 
#               Type of random forest: classification
#                     Number of trees: 500
#No. of variables tried at each split: 2
#
#        OOB estimate of  error rate: 66.67%
#Confusion matrix:
#           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
#setosa          0          0        50           1
#versicolor      0          0        50           1
#virginica       0          0        50           0
```

Class weights are the priors on the outcomes. You need to balance them to achieve the results you want.

---

On `strata` and `sampsize` this answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151341/2874779

In general, `sampsize` with the same size for all classes seems reasonable. `strata` is a factor that's going to be used for stratified resampling, in your case you don't need to input anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a named vector to `classwt`.
But how weight is calculated is very tricky.

For example, if your target variable `y` has two classes "Y" and "N", and you want to set balanced weight, you should do:

```
wn = sum(y="N")/length(y)
wy = 1
```

Then set `classwt = c("N"=wn, "Y"=wy)`

Alternatively, you may want to use `ranger` package. This package offers flexible builds of random forests, and specifying class / sample weight is easy. `ranger` is also supported by `caret` package.

Comment: I guess y = "N" should be changed to y == "N"

Answer (score 2):

Random forests are probably not the right classifier for your problem as they are extremely sensitive to class imbalance.

When I have an unbalanced problem I usually deal with it using `sampsize` like you tried. However I make all the strata equal size and I use sampling without replacement.
Sampling without replacement is important here, as otherwise samples from the smaller classes will contain many more repetitions, and the class will still be underrepresented. It may be necessary to increase `mtry` if this approach leads to small samples, sometimes even setting it to the total number of features.

This works quiet well when there are enough items in the smallest class. However, your smallest class has only 50 items. I doubt you would get useful results with `sampsize=c(50,50,50,50)`.

Also `classwt` has never worked for me.